# PHP Class constructor not running when called from static function in another class

Tags: php, static-methods, static-linking

I am currently stamped and i can't see where I have done it wrong. I have a static function **request()** below:

```
private static function request(){

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

       $data = RunData::get('cmd');

   }
```

which calls a static function **get()** which in turn calls a private function **clean()** which uses variables set in the class constructor loading an Injected class **Sanitize**

```
class RunData {

    public static $sanitize;

    public function __construct( Sanitize $sanitize ){

        self::$sanitize = $sanitize;

    }

   private static function clean($variable_array){    

        if(is_array($variable_array)){

            $filters = array('string' => 'sanitize_string');

            return self::$sanitize->filter($variable_array, $filters);   

        }
    }

    public static function get($variable){

        if(self::clean($_GET)){

            return $_GET[$variable];

        }

    }


}
```

but when I run I get this error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function filter() on a non-object

This filter function is loaded from the **Sanitize** Class which is injected into the constructor.

What possibly have I missed??? The constructor doesn't seem to be running

Thanks

Comment: Constructor will never be called when you simply call class methods statically, so `self::$sanitize` will never be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, `__construct()` is not called when the class is invoked statically. You'll need to set up the object manually by injecting that `Sanitize` class via some sort of setup method before calling the method.

For example:

```
public static function setSanitizeClass(Sanitize $sanitise)
{
    self::$sanitize = $sanitize;
}
```

Then:

```
RunData::setSanitizeClass(new Sanitize());
$data = RunData::get('cmd');
```

Comment: I was trying to see how that can be done without having to initialize other classes or methods. Well it seems I would have to redo some codes, there's no way around it.